# Is there any evidence that this character survived the explosion in X-Men: Apocalypse?

Tags: x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse, marvel

In X-Men Apocalypse, is there any evidence that:

> Havok/Alex Summers

survived the explosion of

> the X-Mansion

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### He ded.

According to interviews Lucas Till (Alex Summers/Havok) did with [CinemaBlend](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1609870/how-one-key-x-men-actor-feels-about-being-killed-off-in-the-series) and [EmpireOnline](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/x-men-macgyver-8-questions-lucas-till/), he was **explicitly told that his character had died in the explosion.**

> *I thought it was really cool. I feel like people are always like 'Oh,
> it's X-Men. It's X-Men you can always come back.' But I was like 'No,
> **I think it's cool that I died.' I think people were kind of nervous to
> tell me that I died but I thought it was really neat.***
>
> <sub><sup>[How One Key X-Men Actor Feels About Being Killed Off In The Series](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1609870/how-one-key-x-men-actor-feels-about-being-killed-off-in-the-series)</sup></sub>

and

> *I figured it was just a matter of time. The producer and writers were
> kind of feeling me out with, **“Are you okay with the fact that you
> die?” and I was, like, “Yes.” That’s something that people would talk
> about, so I thought it was cool that I died.** Havok was in three movies
> and then I get to be remembered. It ended a chapter of my life and I
> get to start a new one with MacGyver.*
>
> <sub><sup>[From X-Men to MacGyver: 8 questions with Lucas Till](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/x-men-macgyver-8-questions-lucas-till/)</sup></sub>

---

That being said, he does recognise that his character could *somehow* return, if the writing requires it.

> *But also it is X-Men and you don't really see me die and if I can withstand cosmic energy coming from my chest I might be able to
> withstand some extreme levels of heat. **Maybe that level fell just
> right so that maybe I survived, I don't know.** I thought it was cool
> though.*
>
> <sub><sup>[How One Key X-Men Actor Feels About Being Killed Off In The Series](http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1609870/how-one-key-x-men-actor-feels-about-being-killed-off-in-the-series)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, no. However, it should be noted that this *is* an X-Men storyline, and the characters have a bad habit, in both the comics and films, to not stay dead. Ray Park's character, Toad, even comments on this, after seeing Jean Grey surviving his earlier slime attack and Storm still being okay after being dropped down an elevator shaft in the first film.

Comment: If there is any way for me to improve this answer, please let me know, and I will do my best.